# Required option not passed: "access_token"

Tags: php, laravel, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working in Graph API which lets user to login through their Microsoft account. I'm following the [Get started with Microsoft Graph in a PHP app](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/php)
article.

Now I'm not new to Laravel, but I can't seem to figure out the issue. I'm using League OAuth2 Package. And according to the link above I should get the Access Token before I'm making the connection. Now, I did a lot searching a debugging on my own and following is what I found.

```
 $token = $this->createAccessToken($prepared, $grant);
```

When it tries to create the token it checks whether `access_token` exists before this or not. Now it is my understanding that `access_token` will be generated from this method. So how could it already exist. Can anyone please help me with this?

Here is my route code:

```
Route::get('/oauth', function (Request $request) {
$provider = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
    'clientId'                => 'client_id',
    'clientSecret'            => 'secret_key',
    'redirectUri'             => 'http://localhost:8000/oauth',
    'urlAuthorize'            => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
    'urlAccessToken'          => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
    'scopes'                  => 'openid'
]);

if (!$request->has('code')) {
    return redirect($provider->getAuthorizationUrl());
} else {
    $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
        'code'     => $request->input('code')
    ]);
    exit($accessToken->getToken());
}
});
```

Thanks.

***Update***

Now I'm making CURL Request Like This

```
    $url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token';
    $data  =  'grant_type=authorization_code';
    $data .=  '&code=' . $request->input('code');
    $data .=  '&client_id=id_here';
    $data .=  '&client_secret=secret_here';
    $data .=  '&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/oauth';
    $data .=  '&scopes=openid user.read';
    $additional_headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    );
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $additional_headers);
    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
    dd($server_output);
```

But the output/response of this CURL request is given a 'token_id' object. Instead of access_token & expiry_in ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't create an Access Token, you're provided one by the authentication provider (Microsoft in this case).

With the `authorization_code`flow you technically receive an Auth Code. You then submit that Auth Code back tot he server to exchange it for a Access Token. You then pass that Access Token in the Authorization header of your calls into Microsoft Graph API.

I have a primer on the v2 Endpoint that walks you through how the OAUTH process works with the Authorization Code flow that you might find helpful: [Microsoft v2 endpoint primer](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/).

UPDATE:

You can't use a tool like `curl` to execute the Authorization Code grant. The first call to `/authorize` is a `GET` that results in a web page the user logs in to. Once that is complete, the authentication provider redirects the user back to your web server which then issues the `POST` to the `/token` endpoint.

If you want to use `curl` (or any other client-side scripting), you need to use the Implicit grant. I have a similar walk through for this: [v2 Endpoint and Implicit Grant](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-implicit-grant/).

Comment: You're right in your article and following the same procedure. But when we get the authorization code, and then initiate the POST request for Access token it gives the above error. Can you tell me what can I use to make a POST request to that URL? Currently I'm using this provider.

     'League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider'

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see which error you're referring too by "above error".

Comment: Now I was successful in making the POST request through curl. But now I'm given back a response of id_token but not what was expected.

Comment: I meant..Required option not passed: “access_token” error.. Now I'm getting token_id instead of the 4 params you mentioned in your article.

Comment: You'll need to either update your question or post an a new one. I'm struggling to understand what you're running into now.